# Number of times $g(p_1)$ occurs in $\sum_{d\mid n}g(d)$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recursion

$$
g(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=1 \\[10pt]
\sum_{d\mid n,\  d\ne n} g(d) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I calculate $g(n)$ efficiently?

I was trying to collect all the $g(p)$ terms after complete decomposition of $n$.

After some googling I found that whay I am looking for is [perfect partition](http://oeis.org/A002033) which is same as [number of ordered factorization](http://oeis.org/A074206) of $n$. There is a formula called [Mac Mohan's formula](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~mays/Papers/Factorizations.pdf) to compute number of ordered factorization of $n$. Can someone explain how Mac Mohan's formula is derived. Also see the [orignal question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13336/number-of-multisets-such-that-each-number-from-1-to-n-can-be-uniquely-expresse).

Comment: Interesting. If $n$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes, I think you get the $k$th term in the sequence http://oeis.org/A000670 --- a sequence that pops up in many places. If $n=p^r$ for some prime $p$ and $r\ge1$, I get $g(n)=2^{n-1}$. Don't know what it looks like in general.

Comment: could you run an example?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you wanted to write $g(n)=2^{r-1}$ if $n=p^r,\ r\geq 1$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: @Samrat, yes, I typoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Let $n$ is square free. Then if $n$ has $\nu(n)$ distinct prime factors, $$f\left(\nu(n)\right):=g(n)=\sum_{d|n,\ d\ne n}g(d)=\sum_{k=0}^{\nu(n)-1}\binom{\nu(n)}{k} f(k)$$ where we denote by $f(k)$ the value of $d(n)$ when $\nu(n)=k$ (because clearly $g(n)$ depends upon the number of prime factors only, not on the prime numbers themselves).

---

So, the function $f(n)$ is defined by $$f(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr} 
1 && \mbox{if}\  n=0\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k} f(k) && \mbox{if}\ n\geq1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I find a striking resemblance of the function $f(n)$ to the [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B(n)$ which is also defined very similarly with a slight (but maybe significant) difference.

To find $g(n)$ for $n$ not square free, we proceed as below.

First, let $n=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Then, $$g(p^k)=\sum_{d|p^k,\ d\ne p^k}g(d)=\sum_{d|p^{k-1},\ d\ne p^{k-1}}g(d)+g(p^{k-1})=2g(p^{k-1})$$
So iteratively, $$g(p^k)=2^kg(1)=2^k$$

Now, let $n=p^kq$ where $p, q$ are distinct prime numbers. Then $$g(p^kq)=2g(p^{k-1}q)+g(p^k)=2g(p^{k-1}q)+2^k$$ Iteratively, $$g(p^kq)=2^kg(q)+k2^k=(k+1)2^k$$

If $n=p^kq^2$ then, similarly we will get the recurrence relation $$g(p^kq^2)=2g(p^{k-1}q^2)+g(p^k)+g(p^kq)$$ Since we know $g(p^kq)$ from the previous computation we can find $g(p^kq^2)$.

Likewise, extending the idea, we get $$g(p^kq^r)=2g(p^{k-1}q^r)+\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}g(p^kq^i)$$

In general, if $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots\ p_r^{k_r}$, then, to find $g(n)$, i guess we have to solve this multidimensional recursive equation $$f_r(k_1,k_2,\cdots\ ,k_r)=\sum_{0\le a_1\le k_1,\cdots\ ,0\le a_r\le k_r}\frac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots\ a_r)!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots\ a_r!}f_r(a_1,a_2,\cdots\ ,a_r)$$ I don't quite know though how to solve this equation.

Right now, I don't see any easier method.

Comment: Thank you for such an great answer. Actually I was trying to solve [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13336/number-of-multisets-such-that-each-number-from-1-to-n-can-be-uniquely-expresse) but got stuck on calculation of $g(n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I am happy that my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: @justiceleague looking at your original problem, it seems still you have to do some research to find a good algorithm to find the $\nu(n)$ and $a_1,a_2,\cdots\ ,a_{\nu(n)}$

Comment: I think your first result is wrong take $n = 6$ and $p = 2$ now $p|n$, so $g(6.2) = 2.g(6)$ but $g(12) = 8$ and $g(6) = 3$

Comment: Oh, correct, that's a serious mistake. I have to change my answer then. Thanks for pointing out @justiceleague.